# Stop network manager from updating resolv.conf

Tags: dns, centos, networkmanager

I changed nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf but when I connected vpn in my CentOS, network-manager pushed my previous DNS back into /etc/resolv.conf.

I do not want network-manager to add DNS servers received from DHCP to my /etc/resolv.conf.

Any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "brute force" way to prevent a file being updated in Linux could be to use [chattr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr), for example you could do:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

To remove the `i - Immutable` attribute so that you could modify the file again run:

```
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Another way could be to configure `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to not modify the DNS:

```
[main]
dns=none
```

From the man:

```
dns
       Set the DNS (resolv.conf) processing mode.

       default: The default if the key is not specified. NetworkManager will update
       resolv.conf to reflect the nameservers provided by currently active connections.

       dnsmasq: NetworkManager will run dnsmasq as a local caching nameserver, using a "split
       DNS" configuration if you are connected to a VPN, and then update resolv.conf to point
       to the local nameserver.

       none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf.
```

Comment: it might be worth to add that when `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`, then this could lead to error `/etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`. as adviced [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking), this can be solved by creating a file `/etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured`, `rm /etc/resolv.conf` and creating a new symlink `ln -s /etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 6):

setting `dns=none` still might allow for the networkmanager to break things - if *DOMAIN* is also specified in the ifcfg-file, NM will still write the file but skipping any dns:es instead recommend setting the following under [main] section:

```
rc-manager=unmanaged
```

this tells networkmanager not to touch `/etc/resolv.conf` at all according to documentation

Comment: At current time (2021-2), this method should be used instead of nbari one.

Comment: From the man page: `If you configure dns=none or make /etc/resolv.conf immutable with chattr +i, NetworkManager will ignore this setting and always choose unmanaged`. So I guess it is not required at all if you set `dns=none`.

Answer (score 1):

I have read several stackoverflow pages that recommend setting rc-manager=unmanaged, instead of dns=none. I just wanted to point out the following documenation from the man page regarding dns=none.

*none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf.* **This implies rc-manager unmanaged.**